# Firefox does not save the form in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, firefox, forms, submit

I've got a form that inserts data into a database using ASP.NET 2.0 .  The problem is that when I hit the submit button on FireFox, the page submits and I'm redirected to the correct page.  The problem is that the data isn't actually saved.

When I try this on IE, it works fine.  When I try this on FireFox using another browser it works fine.  When I mirrored the application and data locally and use FireFox, it works fine.

It just doesn't work on production, and it seems like only my FireFox is having this problem.  I've cleared out the cache in FireFox already, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas what is going on?  I can't tell if this is client side or server side, and there is no way to debug right now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest to install FireBug addon and check posted data.

Answer (score 0):

You say there is no way to debug, can you check SQL Profiler?  That will tell you if anything is happening on the database side.  Also why can you not debug?  The other thing to check is to use firebug and see if there are any issues with your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, disable all plugins in FF and try again. Even better is to create a new profile, see [this topic](http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/profile-tutorial/) for details about profiles. If this will not help - use the answer above.